# What is canonical ID in Pyramid simpleauth

Tags: python, pyramid

I just got started with Pyramid web development and want to use [pyramid_simpleauth](https://github.com/thruflo/pyramid_simpleauth) for my project. I'm not sure what canonical_id is in its User [model.py](https://github.com/thruflo/pyramid_simpleauth/blob/master/src/pyramid_simpleauth/model.py).

It seems to be just a randomly generated string that gets used in its [ACL](https://github.com/thruflo/pyramid_simpleauth/blob/master/src/pyramid_simpleauth/acl.py) somehow, can someone shed me some lights what this does and why it's needed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you want a `canonical_id` is so that you have something to refer the user by that is not their username or email address. Those two entities may change, whereas the `canonical_id` should never change.